# Как в созданном окошке создать два поля для ввода чисел?

Tags: java, swing

Доброго дня! Я сегодня начал разбираться со `Swing` и хочу спросить: как в созданном окошке создать два поля для ввода чисел ? Я смог только создать окошко выставить ему размеры, расположить в середине экрана, а как теперь в этом окошке создать два поля для ввода чисел. Вычитал про `JTextField`, но никак не могу его засунуть, чтобы оно работало! Не откажусь от хорошей литературы по `Swing` или видеоуроков или примеров. Если надо суть программы очень проста: забиваешь числа в эти поля, нажимаешь на кнопку которая будет внизу и программа их умножает!  
**Если в Java есть что-то лучше чем Swing то скажите, может что-то типа PyQt как для Python**

Comment: > Хорстманн Кей, Корнелл Гари - Java 2. Библиотека профессионала

В первом томе кратко о свинг, во втором более глубоко он рассматривается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
JTextField tf1, tf2;
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//blah-blah
tf1 = new JTextField();
tf2 = new JTextField();
//blah-blah
panel.add(tf1); //добавляем 1-е поле
panel.add(tf2); //добавляем 2-е поле
```

Общая канва ясна?

**Update**

В Java есть масса заменителей Swing - в частности, самый известный из них это [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) на котором собственно написана оболочка Eclipse. 
Аналогом Qt/PyQt является [Qt-Jambi](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi) - правда боюсь, что он еще пребывает в глубокой бете.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Comment: Я полагаю, что если Alexey_Ku знает что такое `JTextField`, то он наверное додумался полистать мануал, не?